# Change timezone in Arshaw FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, timezone, fullcalendar

From my understanding, Arshaw FullCalendar displays events according to the timezone of the local computer's operating system. I assume this is done by the javascript Date() object, which also is based on the local computer's operating system. I have an application that has group calendars and a group timezone, I want to be able to force every local Arshaw Calendar to display according to that group's time-zone, no matter what timezone that computer is. How do you do this?

Note: I've looked through the documentation fairly thoroughly, and found no such option. I'm hoping that javascript has something equivalent to php's date_default_timezone_set(), which seems to me the way this could be solved.

*Edit 1/31/2013 12:23pm CST:
I am sending everything to the calendar as unix timestamps, so I assume the option ignoreTimezone would not apply here, as described in this stackoverflow thread:
[jQuery FullCalendar timezone synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840466/jquery-fullcalendar-timezone-synchronization)

Comment: did you asked the question ?

Comment: I have the same problem, but setting the timezone alone may not do the trick, as there are varying daylight-saving periods (ex: Mex has different dates)... so, anyone has an elegant solution for forcing the client to use a given time, regardless of the local time in the client's system (which may also be wrong)???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771609/how-to-ignore-users-time-zone-and-force-date-use-specific-time-zone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably try to set the option "ignoreTimezone" to "false" and give to Arshaw FullCalendar date in ISO8601.

You can get more information about that here: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/ignoreTimezone/

To convert unix timestamps to ISO8601, you can use this in javascript:

```
var d = new Date(1360412434000).toISOString();
```

This is ECMAScript 5.
 See here for compatibility and fallback code: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString