# How to change time zone setting in full calender

Tags: fullcalendar

I changed time zone seating in PHP but not set in full calender with jQuery.
How can change time zone in full calender.
please help me because i trying  to solve this prob in long time.

Thanks 
Ajay Bairagi

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change timezone in Arshaw FullCalendar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14632504/change-timezone-in-arshaw-fullcalendar)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery FullCalendar timezone synchronization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840466/jquery-fullcalendar-timezone-synchronization)

Answer (score 0):

The time is set in the event time format.

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/

> start
>
> Date. Required.
>
> The date/time an event begins.
>
> When specifying Event Objects for events or eventSources, you may
>   specify a string in IETF format (ex: "Wed, 18 Oct 2009 13:00:00 EST"),
>   a string in ISO8601 format (ex: "2009-11-05T13:15:30Z") or a UNIX
>   timestamp.

Comment: Thank for your reply. but I able to change time zone with PHP but not set in full calendar. Full-calender get user system machine date. I want to set time zone with PHP not user system mechine. Thianks Ajay Bairagi

Comment: You might want to check out this: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/ignoreTimezone/